# jQuery Dialog 'Close' conflict with ASP.NET UpdatePanel

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I've got an ASP.NET UpdatePanel with the following:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
    <%-- jQuery dialog - Suppliers --%>
    <div id="divSuppliers" style="display: none;">
        <asp:ListBox ID="lstSuppliers" runat="server" SelectionMode="Single" Rows="10" Width="100%"
            DataValueField="SupplierID" DataTextField="SupplierName">
        </asp:ListBox>
        <br /><br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSelectSupplier" runat="server" Text="Select 2" OnClick="btnSelectSupplier_Click" />
    </div>

    <asp:GridView ID="gvSuppliers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" SkinID="gvSkin"
        DataKeyNames="SupplierID" EmptyDataText="No Existing User Roles">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Supplier Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSupplierName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SupplierName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    <asp:Button ID="btnAddSupplier" runat="server" Text="Add Supplier" 
        Visible="false" OnClick="btnAddSupplier_Click" />

</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSelectSupplier" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Quite simple, really. Nothing more than a div that I use for my jQuery Dialog popup, an ASP.NET GridView control with a single column, and an ASP.NET button for asynchronous postbacks.

Here is the click event that handles the asynchronous postback for btnSelectSupplier.

```
protected void btnSelectSupplier_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    // +=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=    
    // WORKS JUST FINE
    List<SupplierItem> suppliers = new List<SupplierItem>();    

    foreach (int i in lstSuppliers.GetSelectedIndices()) {
        suppliers.Add(
            new SupplierItem { SupplierID = Convert.ToInt32(lstSuppliers.Items[i].Value), SupplierName = lstSuppliers.Items[i].Text });
        lstSuppliers.Items[i].Selected = false;
    }

    gvSuppliers.DataSource = suppliers;
    gvSuppliers.DataBind();

    // +=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=
    // DOES NOT WORK!!
    string jq = "$('#divSuppliers').dialog('close');";

    ScriptManager sm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this);
    if (sm != null && sm.IsInAsyncPostBack) {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
            this, typeof(Page), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            jq, true);
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM:** 
The GridView will update just fine during the asynchronous postback (see the click event above); however, the jQuery Dialog refuses to close (again, see event above and where it says DOES NOT WORK). I'm registering the javascript (jquery) with the ScriptManager on the page and so it should be executing and closing the dialog, but for some reason it doesn't.

**EDIT:**
Code that opens the jQuery dialog and makes it modal.

```
protected void btnAddSupplier_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    lstSuppliers.ClearSelection();
    lstSuppliers.DataSource = Suppliers.GetAllSuppliers();
    lstSuppliers.DataBind();

    string jq = "var dlg = $('#divSuppliers').dialog({ modal: true, draggable: true, title: 'Suppliers', width: 500 }); dlg.parent().appendTo($('form:first'));";

    ScriptManager sm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this);
    if (sm != null && sm.IsInAsyncPostBack) {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
            this, typeof(Page), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            jq, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: can u show u r jquery code? i can able to solve this...

Comment: The only relevant jQuery is included in my code above (see the click event code). The dialog close isn't working for some reason - that's all.

Comment: Have you tried executing `$('#divSuppliers').dialog('close');` in a JS console like Firebug or Developer Console in Safari/Chrome

Comment: Your page includes the jQuery UI library, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The div used for jQuery UI Dialog should be outside the UpdatePanel.

On `btnAddSupplier_Click` you create dialog and move it outside the UpdatePanel.
After `btnSelectSupplier_Click` you have 2 divs with divSuppliers id, the moved one and the one [received from server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (UpdatePanel mechanism allows partial page updates by rebuilding the entire UpdatePanel DOM with html returned from the server).

I would also suggest to use [console.log](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/console.log) to help with debugging.
Add to closing dialog js: `console.log($('#divSuppliers'))`

Comment: You may be right about moving the jQuery Dialog outside of the updatepanel. I actually had it that way at first, but for some reason that I don't recall I moved it inside of the updatepanel. I wouldn't have moved it there without a reason. Anyway, I'll have to do some more testing and see if it works when I get some extra time. I still think I'm just going to rip out the .net junk and just use jQuery with AJAX instead.

Comment: When update panel is updated, its entire html is deleted and updated with content received back from server, including the dialog div, so you are left with 2 divs with same id, the one you moved outside and the one that was recreated from update panel update.

Comment: You should create a new empty `divSuppliersDialog` outside of the update panel and use it for dialog. You will have to use `RegisterClientScriptBlock` to move `divSuppliers` as a child of `divSuppliersDialog` before you display it (as you already do).

Comment: UpdatePanel is a very heavy mechanism. Using jQuery ajax instead of UpdatePanel would be a smart move. I would suggest to try [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) with next projects.

Comment: I'm aware of the differences between .NET's AJAX solution (scriptmanagers and updatepanels) and jQuery's. .NET's solution, although invoking more overhead, can be simpler to implement. Using jQuery AJAX tends to take more time to setup, or at least in my experience. And regarding ASP.NET MVC, I realize that it suits jQuery better than web apps, but that fact in itself doesn't mean that one should use MVC over web apps simply because they're using jQuery. Thanks for your help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered going a simpler route and binding an event to the button client side to close the dialog box?

```
 $(function () {
    $('#btnSelectSupplier').click(function () {

        $('#divSuppliers').dialog('close');
    });
});
```

The flow is still the same from a user perspective. They click the button and the dialog closes. The server side code will run after the dialog closes but since there doesn't seem to be any server side logic that decides whether you want to close the dialog or not after the click, this may fit your needs.

**EDIT** I see your problem. You are running into an issue because instead of opening up your existing dialog, you are redefining the dialog on click:

```
 string jq = "var dlg = $('#divSuppliers').dialog({ modal: true, draggable: true, title: 'Suppliers', width: 500 }); dlg.parent().appendTo($('form:first'));";
```

Instead, you want to define the dialog in the document.ready function.

```
 $(function () {
    //define the div as a dialog. By default, it will not open until you tell it to
$('#divSuppliers').dialog({ modal: true, draggable: true, title: 'Suppliers', width: 500 });

});
```

On the click, you should open it like this

```
 $('#divSuppliers').dialog('open');
```

Once again you may want to do this client side instead of trying to push the script into the page on the server side event but that is up to you.

**Simplest full solution:**

```
$(function () {

$('#divSuppliers').dialog({ modal: true, draggable: true, title: 'Suppliers', width: 500 });

$('#btnAddSupplier').click(function () {

    $('#divSuppliers').dialog('close');
});
$('#btnSelectSupplier').click(function () {

    $('#divSuppliers').dialog('open');
});
});
```

Comment: This works, but only the first time that I click on btnSelectSupplier. If I reopen the dialog (this is done by clicking on a different button) and then click on the btnSelectSupplier it doesn't close the dialog. I put an alert into the btnSelectSupplier click event to make sure that it is being raised each time the button is clicked, and the alert did show up. It's almost like the div for the jquery dialog isn't being found after the first time that it's closed.

Comment: I updated my answer after seeing your updates. You were redefining the dialog on click instead of calling the .dialog('open') function.

Answer (score 0):

So here's the solution: don't try to mix using the ASP.NET UpdatePanel with the jQuery Dialog, because they just don't play nicely together.

I'd only gone this direction because I thought that it would take me less time getting AJAX in place by using .NET's ScriptManager and UpdatePanel controls instead of doing it all in jQuery. At this point it appears I was wrong, because I'm going back and ripping out the .NET junk and replacing it all with jQuery. So all of that time that I thought I'd save is gone like the wind.

Moral of the story: don't mix the two if you don't have to.